# @try @catch doesn't work objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, try-catch

Running the code results in a crash.

```
 -(NSString*) ExtractStringKeyValue:(NSString*)key
{
    @try {
    NSRange  start = [_responceInfo rangeOfString:key];
    NSRange end  = [[_responceInfo substringFromIndex:start.location + start.length+2] 
                      rangeOfString:@"\""];

    NSRange rang = NSMakeRange(
                               start.location + start.length+1
                               , end.location+1);
    return [_responceInfo substringWithRange:rang];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"finally");
    }
}
```

**Debug console:**

2012-02-27 01:10:16.254 Clicky[8665:9203] Exception: *** -[NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds

2012-02-27 01:10:16.255 Clicky[8665:9203] finally

Help please.

Comment: First of all, you should edit your question, so we can clearly see your problem without having our eyes bleeding.

Comment: Can you post some values of `_responceInfo` and `key` where you get the error? Also there are 2 lines with `substringWithRange`, in which one do you get the error?

Comment: You offer no evidence (in your latest incarnation of your code and messages) that the exception handler didn't work.  Where is the crash message (and traceback)?

Answer (score 2):

As we can see the output in Console, your code goes through the @finally block:

```
2012-02-27 00:28:02.794 Clicky[8409:9203] finally
```

And according to the error message `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'`, I can tell you, that your problem is not in this method.

Comment: @VlasenkoDmitry you better post your **real** method with the **real**  console output. Because this method is completely different from that, you initially posted.

Comment: It's real method and real console output.

Comment: @VlasenkoDmitry -- Where is the console output?  Traceback?

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from the method if the @try block fails, there's no string to return...

```
-(NSString*) ExtractStringKeyValue:(NSString*)key
{
    NSString *extractedString = nil;
    @try {
    NSRange  start = [_responceInfo rangeOfString:key];
    NSRange end  = [[_responceInfo substringFromIndex:start.location + start.length+2] 
                      rangeOfString:@"\""];

    NSRange rang = NSMakeRange(start.location + start.length+1, 
                               end.location+1);
    extractedString = [_responceInfo substringWithRange:rang];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"finally");
    }
    return extractedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `substringFromIndex` anywhere in the code you cut & pasted, so the reason why your @try / @catch block isn't working is because the Exception you see here is not coming from that code.  :-)